# How Can we display a legend in high chart that contains apostrophe

Tags: highcharts

While working on High charts I came across an issue as below:
The High charts JSON object breaks if it finds an apostrophe. Now after fetching the Data from Database we have some String which contains an apostrophe and that string should come as legend of High charts.
So does anyone has idea How to make the High charts to display such Strings as legend.

Comment: How your string looks like?

Comment: It is like O'Conner, but below solution by epoch worked fine Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific and paste it here?

Comment: series:[{name:'Locality: O'CONNOR, 6163 - Sale Price(11 Months) - Houses',data: ..... but no worry it is working fine now I have just added \ in front of apostrophe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape it with `\`, i.e: `\'`:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/C5Gpe/)**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tok\'yo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New Y\'ork',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```